# Integration a deep learning model with ROS

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, ros, lidar

I am using **VLP-16** velodyne sensor, I try to detect pedestrians by some deep learning methods.
But I don't know **how to use the trained model with ROS**.
For example, write a ros node to get the trained model and integrate it with other packages such as velodyne_driver.

I would be grateful if someone could give me some suggestions to achieve it.

Thanks:)

Comment: Start by finding out the input types to your DL framework's models. Then find the type of the ROS message that you expect the sensor to emit. Your problem will reduce to mapping the second type to the first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you please give me some examples? I'm new to ROS system, if there are any packages to learn, I would have a better understanding of the integration.